# PopScope does not work if BottomSheetModal is closed by dragging

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

**Case:** There is a form where user information is entered. Individuals are shown with this form modal. I want to block the modal's direct connection if the user form has made a login. I'm shown the throw dialog based on the x button. But I cannot prevent this if the modal is closed by dragging. ***If any information has been entered into the form, the discard dialog should be displayed when trying to close it by dragging.***
Below is sample code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const NavigatorPopHandlerApp());

class NavigatorPopHandlerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigatorPopHandlerApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => const _HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _HomePage();

  @override
  State<_HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Page One'),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return const _FormModal();
                  },
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Show Bottom Sheet'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FormModal extends StatefulWidget {
  const _FormModal();

  @override
  State<_FormModal> createState() => _FormModalState();
}

class _FormModalState extends State<_FormModal> {
  void _showDiscardDialog() {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text(
            'Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Nevermind'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Leave'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(color: Colors.black54, height: 4, width: 48),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text('This is a modal'),
              PopScope(
                canPop: false,
                onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
                  if (didPop) {
                    return;
                  }
                  _showDiscardDialog();
                },
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _showDiscardDialog();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any news? I have this same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please place this code at the beginning of the `_FormModal` widget structure.

```
WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (widget.onFormChanged(true)) {
          return true; // Form has changed, allow back navigation
        } else {
          _showDiscardDialog(); // Show discard dialog
          return false; // Prevent back navigation
        }
      },
```

Comment: Willpopscope is deprecated